# Sudden termination of Apple Developer account, seeking community advice

Tags: terminal, developer-program, accounts

I'm facing an unfortunate issue with my Apple Developer Program membership which was suddenly terminated. I received a generic email from Apple, stating that my membership was revoked, but no specific reason was provided for this action.

I appealed the decision, offering all possible explanations and commitments to adhere to guidelines, only to be met with a reply stating that the decision is "final" and no subsequent appeals will be processed.

Has anyone here faced a similar situation? Are there any steps that can be taken to understand the reason for termination when Apple doesn't disclose it? Is there a way to open a dialogue with Apple, even when they've stated that their decision is final? Would publicizing this issue through social media or blogs be advisable? This is a particularly trying time for us, as we are recovering from a recent earthquake and our app is our sole source of income.

Any insights, advice, or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated.

We didn't violate any of Apple's policies. We have tried to understand the issue and sought clarification but they replied after one day with a final decision.

Comment: It's Apple's house, and their rules. Sorry: I don't know what you can do - perhaps ask a lawyer for advice; or try to open an account with a new email...!

Comment: Can you provide the actual text from the revocation mail? You say that "no specific reason" was given, but perhaps a non-specific reason was given? When you say that you have offered "explanations", what exactly are you trying to explain?